# El nombre de columna 'nroEmpleado' es ambiguo? SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server

estoy realizando la siguiente consulta sin embargo me dice que nombre es ambiguo, he leído en varios sitios y mencionan que es porque tengo 2 columnas iguales y el sql no sabe de que tabla quiero tomar los datos, pero si ven en mi consulta le pongo un alias para indicarle de que tabla quiero que me tome los datos, espero su ayuda.

[image: estas son las 2 tablas que deseo pegar]

esta es mi consulta ...

```
select p.nombres,c.unidad 
from tbl_contratos c 
INNER JOIN tbl_persona p 
ON p.nroEmpleado=c.nroEmpleado WHERE nroEmpleado ='50361'
```

Comment: no le pusiste c o p a nroEmpleado en el where y la base de datos no sabe contra cual comparar

Comment: deberías colocarlo como respuesta @Juan para calificartelo

Comment: @shadow si pongo esto como respuesta me la descalifican y me dicen que debería ser un comentario :(

Comment: por que? @Juan yo la veo válida pues el Op no supo identificar que requeria hacer esa aclaración en su SQL, no es lo mismo que si tuviera error de sintáxis

Comment: @Juan Como respuesta es correcta, quizás sea conveniente añadir porqué hay confusión con ese nombre de tabla.

Comment: Por cierto, estás pasando en las capturas lo que parecen ser NOMBRES Y APELLIDOS COMPLETOS de PERSONAS REALES. ***NO HAGAS ESO***. Si no son relevantes para la consulta, ocúltalos (y ocúltalos bien, con un caja ocultándolo todo, no con un par de líneas). Si son relevantes para la consulta, prepara una tabla con nombres y apellidos ficticios.

Answer (score 1):

Como @juan te comento.
cuando utilizar alias en tablas debes hacer referencia con el alias en toda la consulta.

```
select p.nombres,c.unidad 
from tbl_contratos c 
INNER JOIN tbl_persona p 
ON p.nroEmpleado=c.nroEmpleado WHERE c.nroEmpleado ='50361'
```

o

```
select p.nombres,c.unidad 
from tbl_contratos c 
INNER JOIN tbl_persona p 
ON p.nroEmpleado=c.nroEmpleado WHERE p.nroEmpleado ='50361'
```

segun sea el caso que necesites

Answer (score 0):

debes usar un alias en el where tambien

```
select p.nombres,c.unidad 
from tbl_contratos c 
INNER JOIN tbl_persona p 
ON p.nroEmpleado=c.nroEmpleado WHERE c.nroEmpleado ='50361'
```

en el where siempre usa la columna de la tabla que tenga indice si existe sino escoge cualquiera.

Comment: `where siempre usa la columna de la tabla que tenga indice o sea pk para mejor performance.` ¿? Las condiciones del `where` son las que tengan sentido para el query. Si tienes una serie de condiciones que se usen a menudo para relaciones, puede ser convienente **considerar si vale la pena** crear un índice. Que es muy diferente de lo que tú dices.

Comment: Correcto, pero no era el punto, depende de la condición obviamente y los filtros que se vayan aplicar, a lo que me refiero es que si tiene un indice en la tabla contratos con nroEmpleado y en la otra no, usar de preferencia la de contratos. Por eso no digo crear un indice sino siempre usar la columna que tenga un indice, si ninguna tiene, usa cualquiera.

Comment: bajan puntuacion a pesar de la aclaracion?

Comment: el detalle es que en tu respuesta haces una aseveración sin mayores argumentos, recuerda que tu respuesta puede estar siendo leida por alguien avanzado o por un novato e indicarle que en el `where` esa condición de se debe cumplir suena confuso

Comment: Gracias creo que por eso están estos comentarios como adicionales o editar la respuesta.